# In CREATE, init with params does fill all attributes

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using RoR 3.1 + Postgres on MacOSX

In my create function I have this:

```
def create
    @power_plant_substrate = PowerPlantSubstrate.new(params[:power_plant_substrate]) <= 1

    @trade = params[:power_plant_substrate][:trade] 

    respond_to do |format|
      if @power_plant_substrate.save

    ...
end
```

(1) should instantiate a new object with params[:power_plant_substrate]

THE PROBLEM:

Right after the creation of my new object @power_plant_substrate some of the attribute are available.

if I check params[:power_plant_substrate] value (trace to console) I can verify that all fields were passed correctly:

```
{"power_plant_id"=>"161", "substrate_id"=>"213", "quantity"=>"1", "periodicity"=>"yearly", "trade"=>"wanted", "price_per_unit"=>"0.00", "total_price"=>"0.00", "currency"=>"USD", "address"=>", Reserved", "transport"=>"pickup_only", "description"=>"afewrqe", "latitude"=>"", "longitude"=>""}
```

However I checked my object right after saving (@power_plant_substrate.save). "trade" attribute is not assigned anymore.

I tried accessing the same attributes in the model in a method that I call after_create, and same problem.

However, the record is available with all fields correctly assigned in the database.

WHY @power_plant_substrate object doesn't appear "fully" assigned after saving?

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that there is a list of attr_accessible in PowerPlantSubstrate model. check if currency and trade are added in that list. If not, then add those.

```
attr_accessible :currency, :trade, . . .
```

Making a few attributes alone as attr_accessible will make it impossible to mass assign other variables. That is why individual assignment worked

If there is not list, try adding

```
attr_accessible nil
```

and see if that works

Comment: that didn't work, but I need to correct my question. The attributes are now assigned before the save ... but not after the save. However your contribution was appreciated. I am refactoring the code see if I can get around this issue. It may be bad coding on my side.

Comment: okay. let me know the issue and the fix when it is done. cheers

Comment: almost! I resolve my problem by moving the code after @power_plant_susbtrate.save in the controller create method to my model and used after_create to run post create logic. That was the correct way to do it. Cheers

Comment: Wait I have just found out that trade attribute was still blank even when accessing from the model in after_create. So the question is still open :( Could you vote Up for the question see if someone else can help.